# Changing value of the listBox

Tags: c#, winforms

In **WinForms** how can I change value of the selected item in the **listBox**?
My code doesn't works:

```
    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Text = "new value";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "new value";
        listBox1.SelectedValue = "new value";
        listBox1.SelectedItem = "new value";
        listBox1.Name = "new value";
    }
```

[image]

**Edit1:**

[image]

Comment: How did you fill the items in the listbox? (I mean edit your question and add codes of that part too)

Comment: I fill it in the **collection** like in the **Edit1**

Comment: `this.listBox1.Items[2] = "new value";`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks, but what if I don't know number of the value? I want to change salected value

Comment: Replace `2` with `this.listBox1.SelectedIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.SelectedIndex, "new Value");
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just :

```
listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = "new Value";
```